# How to create xpath for two next button available on the same page

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

My page contains two next buttons.Here I need to click one particular "Next" button among two. Problem here is both next button have same HTML content.They have unique ID, however its not a static one.It is dynamic one and will change all the time.
Here how can identify my element using any method?

Following parent code I have added for Next button 2.Here We have only one unique identifier called ***uId : 'navigationPanel'***.Could you please help me how I can use this in my xpath creation?

```
<div id="idx_layout_ContentPane_102" class="dijitContentPane idxContentPane wizardNavigationPanel wizardNavigationPanelBottom" data-mojo-props="    'class' : 'wizardNavigationPanel wizardNavigationPanelBottom' , uId : 'navigationPanel' , renderHidden : true ,scParamDataFn : function() { return { 'aria-label' : this.getSimpleBundleString('Region_wizard_navigation') } } " data-mojo-type="idx/layout/ContentPane" role="region" aria-label="Wizard navigation" widgetid="idx_layout_ContentPane_102">
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton idxButtonDerived navPrevious" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_11">
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline idxButtonDerived idxSpecialButton navNext dijitButton" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_12">
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" role="presentation" data-mojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick">
<span id="dijit_form_Button_12" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_12_label" role="button" data-mojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon idxNextPageIcon" data-mojo-attach-point="iconNode"/>
<span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">●</span>
<span id="dijit_form_Button_12_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" data-mojo-attach-point="containerNode">Next</span>
</span>
</span>
<input class="dijitOffScreen" type="button" data-mojo-attach-point="valueNode" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" data-mojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" value=""/>
</span>
```

ID will vary always.I need to identify "Next" button 1.

Comment: In this case you need to take help of parent of these buttons. can you paste the html preceding and following the buttons.

Comment: @pArAs updated parent code.We have one unique identifier called **uId**.Can you please help me how we can use it in our xpath.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this:***

```
//*[contains(@class,'flagButtonText') and contains(@id,'flag_form_Button')][1]
```

*Here [1] at the end of exprn gets the first matching node, which is your "Next" button 1.*

Comment: I ahve tried follow, but it is identifying all button.Not the first one.                                              **//*[contains(@class,'book flagInline flagButtonText') and contains(@data-mojo-attach-point, 'containerNode')][1]**

Comment: send me your webpage link. If u don't want to publish - then send to my gmail:: sree.cs10@gmail.com

Comment: Without VPN you cannot access the link.So please let me know if you need more details.I have pasted whole HTML code for the particular blog.In that I have one unique ID called uId,By using that how i can create my xpath.